# iReport subreport divided by a page break

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

The subreport has two *Detail* bands, the first is "Title" and the second is another subreport.
These bands are divided from each other on two pages.

I tried a lot of properties without result as "ignore pagination" and "split allowed"

My question is: How can I force ireport not to split my subreport on two pages ?

I have some screenshots:

The master report:

[image]

The subreport:

[image]

Another subreport:

[image]

The resulting *pdf* file looks like this:

[image]

Comment: if there is a method to force ireport not to split my subreport on two pages !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using two bands in the principle subreport, put the title and the second subreport into the same band. Then set the `splitType` for that single band to `"Prevent"`. That way, the title and data will be kept together and the split will happen *before* the title if the data will not fit on the page.

#### Edit - Preventing the title from repeating:

Putting the title into the detail band will make it repeat with each set of data. To prevent this, change the `printWhenExpression` to `$V{REPORT_COUNT} == 1`. This will cause it to be printed only once, for the first record, and not for each subsequent loop through the datasource.

Comment: I do not think this is a solution because I use a loop on the second subreport and in this case(the pdf example) I have only one element

Comment: @sadiqmrd I think I understand your issue. If you have multiple instances of the second subreport you wouldn't want the title to be repeated. I have made an edit to my answer to address this.