# Jasper Reports - How to group elements with a table so they only print if at least one row of the table has

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm just wondering how I can set Jasper up with something along the lines of...

*"Print this stuff first, BUT only if the subsequent table at least starts on the same page"*

Note: "Title" and "Summary" aren't jasper title / summary bands.  But just text that describes the data in the table.

[image]

This next picture is what I want to avoid:

[image]

I've tried placing everything in the same band and setting split to prevent, but I do want the table to split immediately.  It would sometimes do this (even though there was enough room for the text, and some of the table):

[image]

Comment: One way to solve it is to put everything in one band like [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491599/ireport-subreport-divided-by-a-page-break

Comment: @johansson.lc if I put everything in one band, how do I get the table of data to split immediately?  When I tried this, it would try to prevent splitting on everything.  So sometimes it would skip a page and print on the next, even though 90% of the page was empty.

Comment: Are the rows of your table in a detail band, or are you using a table component?

Comment: @GenericJon - It's in a table component that's in a detail band.

Comment: What about to set "min height to start group" option?