# Jasper Report How to print ReportElement on next page when it doesn't fit on the same page?

Tags: formatting, jasper-reports

In my code I have large amount of data that is generated to a jasper report inside a subreport that's larger than one page. 
When I print it an unwanted page break happens. One element is sometimes printed on the next page when it doesn't fit on the same page.

what I want to happen:

[image: what i want]

what happens instead:

[image: case now]

here's my code:

```
<group name="ExampleGroup">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[null]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="17" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement key="subreport-1" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="594" height="16" uuid="some uuid"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("DataSource")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("Data")]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
```

I already tried to solve the problem by adding parameters, e.g. splitType="Prevent" or keepTogether="true" but both caused an empty page to happen. The parameters I found are only useful when the band should be printed on the same page. But in my case the generated reportElements shouldn't be splitted up. It's not about the group or the band! Because its content is anyway larger than one page. I didn't found anything about that topic.

Probably it would be helpful adding an expression like Group Expression? But I don't know what to add here to say that the row should be printed on the next page when there's not enough space left.

How could I solve that? I'm thankful for any suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iReport subreport divided by a page break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491599/ireport-subreport-divided-by-a-page-break)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding splitType="Prevent" to the band inside the detail that is called in the subreport.